# UICollectionView Lazy Loading issue. CellForIndexPath is nil at first load

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, lazy-loading

So I was trying to imitate [Apple's LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) to make my own lazying loading UICollectionView. So far it's been loading lazily but the **it never sets the imageviews of the cells in the collectionview at the first load.**

Here's my `cellForItem`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *woID = @"WO";

NSMutableArray *currentArr = [manager.dataDict objectForKey:manager.currentCategory.categoryName];

PaWallObject *object = [currentArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
WOCollectionViewCell *cell = (WOCollectionViewCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:woID forIndexPath:indexPath];




if (currentArr.count > 0) {
    cell.wallObject = object;
    if (object.likesCount) cell.likesCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.likesCount];
    else cell.likesCountLabel.text = @"0";
    if (object.replyCount) cell.replyCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.replyCount];
    else cell.replyCountLabel.text = @"0";
    cell.postTimeLabel.text = [PaDataManager getTimeStr:object.createdAt];
    AVFile *picFile = object.thumbnail;

    if (picFile.isDataAvailable) {
        cell.woimageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:picFile.getData];
    } else  {
        if (!cv.decelerating && !cv.dragging) {
            [self startLoading:object forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        cell.woimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LipsCellBackground.png"];
    }

    //fit
    [cell.likesCountLabel sizeToFit];
    [cell.likesCountLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.likeIcon.frame.origin.x + cell.likeIcon.frame.size.width + 3, 0, cell.likesCountLabel.frame.size.width, 20)];
    [cell.replyIcon setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.likesCountLabel.frame.origin.x + cell.likesCountLabel.frame.size.width+5, 2, 16, 16)];
    [cell.replyCountLabel sizeToFit];
    [cell.replyCountLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.replyIcon.frame.origin.x + cell.replyIcon.frame.size.width + 3, 0, cell.replyCountLabel.frame.size.height, 20)];
}


return cell;
```

}

so at the first load the cv is neither dragging nor decelerating. [self startloading] gets called and the files start to load. Here's the code for startloading

```
- (void)startLoading:(PaWallObject *)wallobject forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath {
AVFile *fileToDownload = [filesInDownload objectForKey:indexpath];
if (fileToDownload == nil)
{
    fileToDownload = wallobject.thumbnail;
    [filesInDownload setObject:fileToDownload forKey:indexpath];
    [fileToDownload getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            WOCollectionViewCell *cell = (WOCollectionViewCell *)[self.cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexpath];
            NSLog(@"load completed, cell is%@", cell);
            cell.woimageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            [filesInDownload removeObjectForKey:indexpath];
        }
    }];
}
```

}

As Apple's sample projects instructs, `[self loadImagesForOnScreenItems]` is called when the cv stops dragging and decelerating. However at the first load there cannot be any touch inputs, so I consider this method irrelevant to my issue.

I looked into the aforementioned `- (void)startLoading:(PaWallObject *)wallobject forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath;` method and discovered when the files, at the first load, finish loading in the completion blocks, `WOCollectionViewCell *cell = (WOCollectionViewCell *)[self.cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexpath];` will always be nil. so the loaded data cannot track cell.woimageview.image because the cell simply doesn't exist. However after this round when I scroll down the list the cells start to have values.

Why? Aren't the cells already generated when `[self startloading:object forIndexPath:indexPath]` is called from `cellForIndexPath` as the cells are dequeued from the collectionView? If not, could anybody provide a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you've *returned* your cell from the `cellForItem...` datasource method, the collection view does not have a cell for that index path, so it returns `nil` in your `startLoading` method, since that is called before the datasource method returns.

Passing the cell as an additional argument to `startLoading` would solve this.

Comment: Thanks! I think it worked! The problem really is `isDataAvailable` doesn't really tell me if the AVFile(identical to PFFile provided by Parse Framework) is already fetched to local disk. It only tells me if it is in memory. Hence when data is returned in the completion block the cell has not been returned yet.